# Sometimes UIView animateWithDuration happens immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

Randomly my app will not animate at all. My app has a sound bar that gets updated every 0.1 seconds with an animation. Usually when I start the app the animations will work all pretty and everything but then at a random point usually after I transition to another view controller (via `setViewControllers`) it all of a sudden stops animationg. It's not just this animation but every animation in my app excluding `setViewControllers`.

Here is my code where I call `setViewControllers`:

```
- (void)goToController:(GeneralViewController *)vc animate:(BOOL)animated sub:(BOOL)sub{
    if(animated){
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSMutableArray *viewController = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[delegate.navController viewControllers]];
        if(viewController.count > 0){
            viewController[0] = vc;
        }else{
            [viewController addObject:vc];
        }
        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.2;
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        if(sub)
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        else
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

        [delegate.navController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
        [delegate.navController setViewControllers:viewController animated:FALSE];
        self.colorStyle = MusicPlusColorStyleLight;
    }else{
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSMutableArray *viewController = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[delegate.navController viewControllers]];
        if(viewController.count > 0){
            viewController[0] = vc;
        }else{
            [viewController addObject:vc];
        }
        [delegate.navController.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:kCATransition];
        [delegate.navController setViewControllers:viewController animated:FALSE];
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use to animate the sound bar:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                       meterViewColor.frame = CGRectMake(0, (meterView.frameSizeHeight - (level*meterView.frameSizeHeight)), meterView.frameSizeWidth, (level*meterView.frameSizeHeight));
                     }
        completion:nil];
```

I have checked and the code is running on the main thread. The CPU was on average around 10% and the Memory was 25 MB. So I am really baffled as to why it stops working sometimes. Has anyone else experienced this?

**UPDATE:** Sorry to say but the answer I posted was incorrect. It still isn't working. I have removed my answer and attached it bellow:

When creating the animation I added:

```
[transition setDelegate:self];

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.navController.view removeTransition];
}

- (void) removeTransition {
    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform)) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading any of your view controllers from the storyboard or a nib?

Comment: @Milo No everything is code based

Comment: IF a set frame or other bit of code hits an error, then the animation instantly completes. You will need to log out and make sure all the frame values are what you expect. If you log out `finished` in the completion I'll bet it is `NO`. Probably some bad math in the frame code.

Comment: @AlexReynolds how can this be true though if the frame goes to the correct position. Only one frame is changed so its not like it is stoping before changing one of the other frames. The animation ends in the right place but just doesn't animate. Also as I said it happens in all animations across my app. Some of those use constants so the frame is not the issue

Comment: Where in your code is the animation run? As in, how is it triggered?

Comment: @LyndseyScott it's triggered by an NSTimer. It is executed on the main thread.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the NSTimer?

Comment: is the BOOL Finished true or false in the completion of the animation?

Comment: @LyndseyScott The timer was initialized on the start of my app in the `applicationDidFinishLoading` method.

Comment: In your app delegate?? Sounds like that may be related to your issue... I think you need to post more code from your applicationDidFinishLoading method and the method containing your animation.

Comment: @AlexReynolds something does seem fishy. When it animates sometimes it completes and sometimes it doesn't. Most likely because the animations are overlapping and cutting each other off. When the animations happen instantly the BOOL is a constant TRUE.

Comment: @LyndseyScott sorry for not elaborating. The NSTimer starts on the initialization of one of my audio playing classes which happens to be in the AppDelegate method. The method the NSTimer calls also checks if `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive` or if the view isn't being displayed and cancels the timer. It's reinitialized in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: Please also note that I use other animatins in my app and all of them happen instantly. Some happen through a timer some happen as the action of a UIButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**: I just undeleted my answer as it seems one of the properties `transitionTransform` should have been just `transform`. So it seems the animation was happening instantly because `self.transform != CGAffineTransformIdentity`. Even though `self` was the UINavigationController view it was still the superview of the views I was trying to animate.

Turns out the animation either wasn't being removed or was being removed at the wrong time.

When creating the animation I added:

```
[transition setDelegate:self];
```

And then in the delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.navController.view removeTransition];
}
```

Where `removeTransition` was a category method on UIView defined as:

```
- (void)removeTransition {
    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform)) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```